# GETting a document within a Document Update Handler

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to query (GET) a document from within a document update handler in CouchDB?

I have written a simple document update handler in CouchDB 2.0 to accept a POST from a third party (CognitoForms). This works fine, and I take the ID from their JSON payload and use that as the doc _id.

You can then specify an 'update' URI in CognitoForms, so I could create a new update handler or use the same one. However, in CognitoForms:

- The update does a POST rather than a PUT
- There does not appear to be a way to send any query parameters

As the ID for the document which needs to be updated is within the body, I could use this to query the database for the document, get the _rev, and return the payload with the _id and _rev to perform the update. However, I simply don't know if I can do such a query within the update handler. I feel like I am either missing something obvious, or there is a very good reason that I wouldn't be allowed to do that.

Thanks very much

edit: I should add that I understand I could create a small application to parse the request before forwarding on to couchdb, but I was interested to see if I could implement this in couchdb only to understand how far I can get without another layer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, it's quite hard to do this. A document update handler is basically a pure function that gets the data it needs and returns a response, but it has no way to reach out into the database.

If you add a doc id to the url, the update function gets the doc from the database as a parameter. For details see [the CouchDB docs for update functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/render.html#db-design-design-doc-update-update-name-doc-id).

The way to a possible solution is to use a rewrite in CouchDB in order to extract the id from the body. In CouchDB 2.0, a new way for [rewrites as functions has been introduced](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/rewrites.html#rewrite-section-a-is-stringified-function).

For pushing the limits, using a rewrite function for this sounds like fun. But for a production use case, it's probably easier and more maintainable to create a small node.js app that parses the body.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. Really good to know about the rewrites feature as it somehow passed me by. I agree that it may not be the best choice for production use but certainly interesting to take a look.